# Rounded corner creates a border between consecutive elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have 2 consecutive elements. Things look fine on Chrome but theres an issue with IE (what a surprise). There is a thing space between the elements that looks like a border but is in fact the background showing through.

This is happening in IE10 and IE9.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwEVwM

[image]

Heading

Bottom

```
body {
  background: blue;
}

.top {
    background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 6px solid #D7D7D7;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #B9B9B9;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.bottom {
    background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 6px solid #D7D7D7;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #B9B9B9;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: looks fine in my case. add `display: block` to both of them, maybe this helps and stop using IE9 :P

Comment: No that doesnt fix the issue for me. What do you mean it looks fine? Are you viewing the link with IE?#

Comment: yep, just viewed it in IE10 and IE9. no background shining through here

Comment: Strange, ive asked some other people at work to test and they are all seeing the blue line.

Comment: http://imgur.com/1nt8Vtf really interesting that this happens. which OS do you use?

Comment: Strange, http://www.browserstack.com/ also doenst have the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really interesting. in IE11 i get the same issue. Try `margin-bottom: -1px` on `top` -> works in IE11.

but i really don't know why this happens. maybe some rounding problems with the shadows, or the `z-index: 0`

Comment: Its not z-index, ive tried removing that. I guess I may have to go with an IE specific stylesheet. Very unimpressive that this is required for simple layouts and the latest version of IE!

Comment: do you use modernizr or some other browser detection? if yes: simply use `.ie11 .top { margin-bottom: -1px }` .. but you are right, really unimpressive!

Comment: Id rather use a specific stylesheet than JS to avoid the 'flash' you get as teh JS kicks in.